# Data saving in Android SDK(jar)

Tags: android

I am creating sdk(single jar file) for GCM.
How do you save data in a jar file?

I am setting activity class to be started when user press the notification, but by the time intent service is called, activity class that I set in start up activity is not defined.

CustomIntentService.java

```
public class CustomIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.id.icon, message, when);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, PushManager.getActivity());
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
}
```

PushManager.java

```
public final class PushManager {
    private Activity startupActivity;

    public void setActivity(Activity activity) {
        startupActivity = activity;
    }

    public Activity getActivity() {
        return startupActivity;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
PushManager.setActivity(this);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? The combination of SDK + JAR (a library project?) and GCM & starting Activities and saving data in a jar does not makes sense

Comment: I am just trying to make sdk(jar) file, so all of my applications uses same library to send GCM.
I am stopped at starting up an activity each app wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this using preferences.